# Conditional for specific page

Tags: url, conditional

I'd like to only load some scripts for 1 specific page with the Url `/projects/`.

Currently I'm using:

```
{% if craft.app.request.segments|first == 'projects' %}
 // load scripts
{% endif %}
```

This works.

However, I also have pages with the Url `/projects/project-name` which should not load the script.

How can you perform a conditional test for just the Url `/projects/` ?

Thanks

Comment: `{% if craft.app.request.segments|last == 'projects' %}` did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either  `| last` filter instead of first or, a combination of first and another conditional ( segments[1] is empty or similar)?

```
{% set segments = craft.app.request.segments %}
{% if segments | first == “projects” and segments[1] is empty %}
Load scripts
{% endif %}
```

On phone so ymmv

Comment: You might also be able to just test craft.app.request.uri or something (path?) check the request docs?

Answer (score 1):

You might check if `projects` is part of URL:

```
{% if 'projects' in craft.app.request.segments|split('/') %}
Load scripts
{% endif %}
```